# Video lightbox not functioning

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a video lightbox to a website but it does not work. Here is the code I have written,

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/vid.png"  alt="" /><br /> Watch Video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure your `onclick` handler there is invalid.

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp5nbthm/2), see if that helps.

The code in it is,

**HTML**:

```
<div id="light" hidden>stuff</div>
<div id="fade" hidden>stuff</div>

<a id="watchVideo" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="/images/vid.png"/>
    <br/> 
    Watch Video
</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementById("watchVideo").addEventListener("click", function displayVideo() {
    document.getElementById('light').hidden = false;
    document.getElementById('fade').hidden = false;
});
```

Comment: The JSFiddle link does nothing.

Comment: Edited, check now @ShenXu.